# What is the replacement class for SerializerBase in FasterXML Jackson 2?

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I am upgrading to Jackson 2. I have many custom serializers extending SerializerBase (`org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase`). What's the new equivalent class in Jackson 2

Answer (score 11):

Looks like StdSerializer is the new replacement (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer`)